Continuity equation on Riemannian manifolds
I'm currently reading through Villiani's Optimal transport books and am trying to understand the form of the continuity equation for the volume form on an $n$-dim Riemannian manifold $X$ in a situation where the metric changes along a flow - it seems the continuity equation should be modified? From the viewpoint of moving along a flow $\Phi(x,t)$ on $X \times \mathbb{R}$ as per Frankel, the Geometry of physics, Theorem 4.42, section 4.3c:
Let $\phi_t: X \rightarrow X$ be a 1-parameter family of diffeomorphisms, and $\mu_t(x) = \rho(x,t) \, \text{dVol}_t \in \Omega^n(X)$ be a one-parameter family of top forms on $X$, letting $X_t := \phi_t X$, and moving along the flow generated by $V = \bf{v} + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ on $X \times \mathbb{R}$:
$$ \begin{align}\frac{d}{dt} \int_{X_t} \mu_t &= \int_{X_t} \frac{\partial \mu_t}{\partial t} + \iota_{\bf{v}} d\mu_t + d\iota_{\bf{v}}\mu_t \\
&= \int_{X_t} \frac{\partial \mu_t}{\partial t} + (\textsf{div} \, \bf{v})\mu_t \\
&= \int_{X_t} \frac{\partial (\rho_t \text{dVol}_t)}{\partial t} + (\textsf{div} \, \rho\mathbf{v}) \text{dVol}_t
\end{align} (*)$$
Formally interpreting $\mu_t$ as a measure, so $\int_{X_t} \mu_t = 1 \, \forall \, t$, we get
$$ \frac{\partial \rho_t}{\partial t} + \rho_t\frac{1}{2}\textsf{Tr}\left(\frac{\partial g_t}{\partial t}\right) + \textsf{div} \, \rho_t\mathbf{v} = 0~.$$
Where we've used $\frac{\partial \text{dVol}_t}{\partial t} = \frac{\rho}{2} \textsf{Tr}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)$.
In contrast, the standard continuity equation on manifolds ignores the evolution of the volume form w.r.t. time,
$$ \frac{\partial \rho_t}{\partial t} + \textsf{div} \, \rho_t\mathbf{v} = 0~.$$
But it seems that the metric must change along a generic flow, and therefore $\partial g_t /\partial t$ cannot be ignored - must the continuity equation be augmented if the metric changes? Is it standard to fix the metric in these situations?
Edit: in $(*)$ we've used the definition of the Lie derivative and Cartan's magic formula in the first line, the definition of the divergence in the second and closure of $\mu_t$, and the fact that $d\iota_{\mathbf{v}} \rho \alpha = d\iota_{\rho \mathbf{v}} \alpha$ in the third.
